# syntax error: bad string token

Tags: html, syntax-error, reddit

I'm making some hover boxes for a subreddit, but I keep getting syntax error: bad string token. I'm not sure what is causing the error as im just starting to write code. Also if this is too vague or not formatted correctly let me know.

```
<div class="outerbox">
  <div class="innerbox" >
    What's This Sub All About</div> Lyle Stevik is currently lying in an unmarked grave. We believe that he might have friends or family out there who are looking for 'closure'. You can help!
  </div>
```

Comment: a div is just a container, you should be placing text inside HTML elements like <label> or <textarea>

Comment: Your HTML is valid, and it works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/30jdja8p/

Comment: It works on jsfiddle but gives me errors on reddit...I copy and pasted a section of the code from jsfiddle could that be a problem?